# When you don't know what it is

Tags: riddle, word

What's the word I'm thinking of?

*Clue 1:*

> You put it in your mouth to use it, but you can't eat it or taste it.

*Clue 2:*

> People often point when they use it, but you can't see it or touch it.

*Clue 3:*

> Everyone knows how to use it, but you only use it when you don't know what it is.

Comment: NANI? Nice riddle tho

Comment: Hi Gollum, no need for spoilers here - they should only be used to hide *optional* content. (Here, what you hid was the entire riddle itself, rendering it unsolvable without revealing the info!) I've fixed that for you now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is

> The word "what"

You put it in your mouth to use it, but you can't eat it or taste it.

> You voice the word "what" to use it but the word has no specific taste.

People often point when they use it, but you can't see it or touch it.

> If they are about to say "What is that?", for example, then a person may point to the object in question.

Everyone knows how to use it, but you only use it when you don't know what it is.

> Everyone knows how to ask a "what" question and it's generally only used when you don't know to what the "what" is referring.

What's the word I'm thinking of

> Yes, exactly.

Comment: Marked as accepted (nice work); not sure of etiquette, if I should delay that acceptance or trust the spoilers not to ruin it for others?

Comment: @Gollum Thanks! There's no real fixed etiquette. I've seen some award quickly while others wait a while. Completely up to you how you do it.